# Defining a Redshift connection in DataGrip

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, datagrip

I'm trying to define a Redshift connection in DataGrip but couldn't find any Redshift driver in the UI. I tried using both Postgres and generic Database Driver with no luck.

Has someone been able to configure this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DataGrip added the native support for Amazon Redshift. So now it became a lot easier. [image]

Answer (score 52):

If you want to connect DataGrip to Redshift I suggest you use the [jdbc drivers from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html). Just download them to a directory where you can keep them.

Then you open DataGrip and go to the data sources menu (⌘;).
[image: File -> Data Sources...]

Right-Click on one of the pre-installed drivers or somewhere in the driver section. And select 'Add → Driver'
[image: Add -> Driver]

Give it a good name like 'Redshift' and in the bottom part, click on the + Symbol under Driver files, select the driver you just downloaded and click OK.
[image: Add the driver]

Under class, select com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver, under Dialect, select PostgreSQL.
[image: Select Class and Dialect]

Now you can go to the data sources menu (⌘;) and click on the "+" symbol in the top left corner and select the Driver you just created (in my case it's called "Redshift") as the data source type.
[image: Select Driver for new Connection]

Now copy your redshift jdbc url (you can find it in your cluster configuration under "Cluster Database Properties") into the URL field and fill the user and password fields with your credentials.
[image: JDBC url]

Now can you click on "Test Connection" and it should work.

I hope this helps. If you have further questions or problems to follow the instructions, feel free to comment.

Comment: The URL that worked for me was: `jdbc:redshift://****.****.eu-central-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/*****` (unchanged from the one provided on the console)

Comment: I think I am running into [the issue mentioned here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/tag/redshift/), which they say is fixed. On version `2017.1.1`.

Comment: For me that was never an issue for me. Where you able to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I succeed after all with Postgres driver (I had to add SSH tunnel - not relevant for this problem

Comment: But you still don't know how to plug redshift database, right?

Comment: @moscas, what I meant is that I succeeded to connect to Redshift using a Postgres driver.