# Configuring the database driver for AWS Redshift in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: jdbc, intellij-idea, pycharm, amazon-redshift

AWS **Redshift** has a PostgreSQL query interface. So I tried to set-up a connection to a cluster with the **PostgreSQL driver** driver in **PyCharm** (JetBrain IDE family): it works but there is one background job that keeps failing. The error message is:

```
AWSmytestdb.pg_catalog.padb_config_harvest
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to determine a value for MaxIndexKeys due to missing system catalog data.
```

Does **AWS Redshift** set a value for **MaxIndexKeys** at all? Does this matter? Can I turn the job off? Is there a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the jdbc driver provided by amazon.
in this post I described how to install and use it in DataGrip (also Jetbrains).

[Defining a Redshift connection in DataGrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392663/defining-a-redshift-connection-in-datagrip/36741361#36741361)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure connection using native Redshift driver, instead of Postgres.
It did help me with updating schema metadata in PyCharm.

1. download drive .jar file (at the time of writing it is ***RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar***: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver)
2. Configure new DB driver in PYCharm/Intellij:
   [image]
   [image]
3. Configure new DB connection, using your new driver:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this error for over a year and it never affected any Redshift/SQL functionality in Intellij IDEA (same family of products as PyCharm)